# VBA Replace using inequality

Tags: excel, vba, performance, loops, replace

I have a frequent data process for a client that has to be Excel VBA. It's 3000x60 grid of cells on 6 tabs, so it can take a while to loop. The test task is to find values `>5` and highlight them.

Conditional formatting is not an option for various reasons.

A for loop is obvious, and I'm open to that, but I'm looking for a speed improvement.

Replace seems faster. I want to try Selection.Replace What:=">5" but that looks for the string not the inequality I really want.

Comment: Bring your block of data into an internal VBA array.  Then loop on the array.

Comment: Create & loop an array then modify array dimensions position to meet sheet address in order to format correctly.

Comment: The array should be faster. thanks. got any more details on how to do that efficiently?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this is an interesting approuch?

```
Sub Highlight()

Dim WS As Worksheet

For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    For X = 1 To 60
        On Error Resume Next
        With Intersect(WS.UsedRange, WS.Columns(X))
            .AutoFilter 1, ">5"
            .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Interior.Color = vbYellow
            .AutoFilter
        End With
        On Error GoTo 0
    Next X
Next WS

End Sub
```

Obviously there is plenty of room for improvement (turn of screenupdating and calculation for example) but you should get the idea. I have no clue if it is faster :). At least you won't be looping all cells.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is promising. Thanks so much. I am getting an improper result if no values in a column match. In that case, the whole column becomes yellow.
I put a conditional on the yellow highlighting. Let me know if you think of any other simplification. Thanks

`If .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count > 1 Then`

Comment: This is working really well. marked correct. I thought autofilter would operate more slowly, but it's doing a lot of good. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: @jasontoroy, glad it helped you out :). Surprised how fast this routine can be indeed. Did you do a timecomparison by any chance?

Comment: yes and no. I actually added a timer for everything. it runs in 30sec or so but up to 2min depending on input size and error quantity. source data is a changing collection of 1-6 imported csv files. Anyway, it's pretty fast with the autofilter (and running only when necessary)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
Sub Highlight()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Dim row As Long, col As Long, ws As Variant
    For Each ws In Worksheets
    For row = 1 To 3000
    For col = 1 To 60
        If ws.Cells(row, col).Value > 5 Then ws.Cells(row, col).Interior.ColorIndex = 4 'light green
    Next
    Next
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: *"A for loop is obvious, and I'm open to that, but I'm looking for a speed improvement. "*

Comment: @GSerg Updated answer with slight improvement :)

Comment: @MichałTurczyn in my opinion no need to loop. just use `.UsedRange`. Moreover `col = 1 To 6` is wrong. it should be `col = 1 To 60`

Comment: I can do a loop for sure. Any thoughts on Replace with an inequality?